# I am getting an error that reads "Use of Undeclared Identifier 'event'"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, error-handling

I am getting an error that reads "Use of Undeclared Identifier 'event'" that appears on this line. Can someone help?

```
UIView *senderView = [[event.allTouches anyObject] view];
```

Here is the code.

```
  }
  -  (void)didTap_tabBarItem1 {
      CurrentItemsViewController *controller = [[CurrentItemsViewController alloc] init];
      UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
         initWithRootViewController:controller];
      [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
      UIView *senderView = [[event.allTouches anyObject] view];
      CGRect senderFrame = [senderView convertRect:senderView.frame toView:self.view];
      self.tabBarItem1Popover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController
         ] autorelease];
      [self.tabBarItem1Popover presentPopoverFromRect:senderFrame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:
         UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
      [navigationController release];
      [controller release];
   }
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure the error message could be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's all because in you use undeclared variable event. You don't pass it to your method `- (void)didTap_tabBarItem1`. You can do something like this `- (void)didTap_tabBarItem1:(UIEvent *)event` but you should pass this `event` variable to this method.

Comment: Sorry, I am really new at all this. This is the one error I cant figure out how to fix

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any variable named event

Did you copy and paste this code?

Comment: The sooner you stop that the better.  It will only hurt your understanding.